C++ Get IDispatch Pointer from SafeArray of VT_DISPATCH type
I have a problem to determinate a valid IDispatch pointer from a SAFEARRAY of type VT_DISPATCH.
What is the right approach?
So far, my experiences are, I always get an exception when trying to AddRef the pointer.
    if (vtS == VT_DISPATCH) {
        IDispatch* iDisp = NULL; void* pData = NULL;
        if (idx) {
            ret = SafeArrayPtrOfIndex(SA, idx, &pData);
            if (ret) goto CleanUp;
        }
        iDisp = (IDispatch*)pData;
        iDisp->AddRef();
        pVGet->vt = VT_DISPATCH;
        pVGet->pdispVal = iDisp;
    }

Please give me a working sample for.

When using SafeArrayPtrOfIndex there's an extra level of indirection, so you should change your code like this:
void* data;
SafeArrayPtrOfIndex(sa, &idx, &data);

auto disp = *(IDispatch**)data;
disp->AddRef();

Or just use SafeArrayGetElement (and you're supposed to lock the array when using SafeArrayPtrOfIndex):
IDispatch* disp;
SafeArrayGetElement(sa, &idx, &disp);
disp->AddRef();


Why SafeArrayLock? It is for thread safety?

Yes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraylock#thread-safety
